# OwnCloud 8.0.1 on Raspberry Pi - Untrusted Domain

Tags: php, nginx, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, owncloud

First question ever here...

I have OwnCloud running on a Raspberry Pi 2. 
I can access it locally with no issues.
Ports 22, 80, and 443 have been forwarded.
I can SSH into the machine from outside local.

But, if I try to access http/https from outside of my local network, I get:

> "You are accessing the server from an untrusted domain.
>   Please contact your administrator. If you are an administrator of this instance, configure the "trusted_domain" setting in config/config.php. An example configuration is provided in config/config.sample.php. 
>   Depending on your configuration, as an administrator you might also be able to use the button below to trust this domain."

I have the following in my config.php:

```
'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.10.10'
  ),
```

Commenting it out fixes the problem, but that's not the best solution.

I've spent some time looking around forums looking for answers and feel I have everything set up correctly. I'm just missing something...

FYI the router is an ASUS RT-N66W

Answer (score 2):

When you're accessing it remotely, you're not using `192.168.10.10`, you'd be using a public IP address or external hostname.  It's this which you need to add to your trusted domains.  Let's say you're accessing it using an external IP of `12.34.56.78`:

```
'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.10.10',
    1 => '12.34.56.78'
  ),
```

And if you also decide to use an external hostname:

```
'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => '192.168.10.10',
    1 => '12.34.56.78',
    2 => 'owncloud.mydomain.com'
  ),
```

You can add as many of those as is necessary for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Nicks remarks there is also the example config file (config.sample.php) that helps you understand how to manipulate the real config file (config.php).

In case somebody wonders where to find the configuration files:
you will find them here

/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php

/var/www/owncloud/config/config.sample.php